# How to hide/remove Rhythmbox Now playing pop-up/notification?

Tags: rhythmbox

Everytime a song is played on Rhythmbox from my playlist a pop-up on the upper-right side of the screen shows. How could I hide it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The infamous popup you are referring to is the Ubuntu notification system.

You'll see that with a variety of applications - weather apps, empathy as well as plugging in external devices.

However if you specifically dont like rhythmbox displaying a notification about which song is playing, it is simple enough to disable it.

From the rhythmbox global menu choose `Edit-Plugins` or `Tools > Plugins`, scroll down and deselect *Notification*

[image: pic]

N.B. The global menu can be revealed by hovering your mouse at the top of the screen over the top of the panel which is called the menubar.

Comment: Any idea how to launch this dialog from the command line?  I'm using i3 to avoid stuff like this.  I'm surprised this got through when even some critical stuff I want like automounting usb drives doesn't...

Comment: @AndrewWagner look at editing via "gsettings" the setting org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins.active-plugins.  You'll need to remove the notification plugin from the list.

Comment: In 2018, ubuntu 16.04, I opened rhythmbox, went to Tools > Plugins, and disabled the plugin seen above.

Comment: Thanks, these notifications was really annoying

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @fossfreedomg's comment: This is how I did it in Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins active-plugins "['artsearch', 'audiocd', 'audioscrobbler', 'cd-recorder', 'daap', 'dbus-media-server', 'generic-player', 'ipod', 'iradio', 'mmkeys', 'mpris', 'mtpdevice', 'power-manager']"
```

You can list your current settings via:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins
```

Answer (score 4):

Just had this problem myself and glad to find an answer.

On Ubuntu 20.04 I searched for Notifications and got the following...

[image: Notifications]

When you click the RhythmBox choice you'll see a poup that lets you control things more specifically:

[image: rhythmbox notifications popup]

I turned off the Notification Popups and it solved the problem.

[image: Notifications popup turned off]

The note just means that if you look in the notifications area you will still see a notification of the current song that is playing.  However, it won't popup on the screen any longer.

Comment: This was a better solution than the accepted answer for me as when disabling just the notification plugin, a little "Next" notification still appeared between songs. This was in Mint 20.1 Ulyssa Xfce 4.14.2 edition.